# Serve audio file with Spring boot

Tags: spring, angular, spring-boot

I'm using Spring boot 1.5 with Undertow to serve an angular 5 application. The application it's working but I have the following issue.

I want to play an audio file on the client and I can't. On the browser I can confirm that the audio file exist with status code 206 Partial Content but is unable to play the audio file when it's needed. When I access directly the file from the browser "http://localhost:8080/app/assets/audio/beep-sound.mp3" I can listen to the audio.

Also when I serve the application using angular-cli the audio it's working fine. 
Do I need any configuration in the spring boot to enable this functionality?

Thanks in advance

```
/*HTML file*
<audio #audioOption>
  <source src='assets/audio/beep-sound.mp3' type="audio/mp3">
</audio>

@ViewChild('audioOption') audioPlayerRef: ElementRef;
...
this.audioPlayerRef.nativeElement.play();
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution on my problem. Here is what was needed in spring boot.

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties({ ResourceProperties.class })
public class StaticResourcesConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    static final String[] STATIC_RESOURCES = new String[] { 
            "/**/*.css", 
            "/**/*.html", 
            "/**/*.js", 
            "/**/*.json",
            "/**/*.bmp",
            "/**/*.jpeg",
            "/**/*.jpg",
            "/**/*.png",
            "/**/*.ttf",
            "/**/*.eot",
            "/**/*.svg",
            "/**/*.woff",
            "/**/*.woff2",
            "/**/*.mp3"
    };

    @Autowired
    private ResourceProperties resourceProperties = new ResourceProperties();

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler(STATIC_RESOURCES).addResourceLocations(resourceProperties.getStaticLocations());
    }
}
```